# Email Readership Image shows in outlook mail as Cross 'x'

Tags: c#, html, css, email, outlook

I am embedding an image in my html mail like this

```
<img src="foo.jpg" width="0" height="0" 
     style="display: none; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" />
```

When the mail is opened in outlook, the image shows as

[image]

But, when the source of mail is saved as html, it is not shown as `height`, `width` is `0` and `display` is `none`.

Why is this so? Am I missing something?

**Note:** I want to know if email has been read so the image src is actually an aspx page having some logic. That's why height width is zero.

Comment: Why're you using `<img>` when you've set `width="0" height="0" 
     style="display: none;...` ??

Comment: why width,height is set as "0" and display:"none" ??

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: I  want to know if email has been read so the image src is actually an aspx page having some logic. That's why height width is zero.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Okay. I got your point then instead of setting all that `width="0" height="0" style="display: none;...` just use an `<img>` of `1px*1px` `height` and `width` and you're good to go. As *outlook* is very keen regarding *Dom* issues.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: What will be the final image tag?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal `<img src="foo.jpg" width="1" height="1" 
     style="display: inline-block; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" />` where your `foo.jpg` will be of `1px*1px` `height` and `width`. So it won't affect your Newsletter or email-template.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: This worked. Thanks. Please put your comment as answer so that I can accept and other users can get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using an `<img>` tag with an image-name in `src` attribute which may be ignored by other *mailing services* but **Outlook** is very keen for *Dom* issues and i.e. why its showing that *red crossed* or *missing image* view.

Instead of that use:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" width="1" height="1" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" />
```

For functionality like this always use *white* or *transparent* image of `1px * 1px` `height` & `width`.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is displaying the icon that indicates that the image "foo.jpg" cannot be located.  This is normal behavior for Outlook.  When you export the message as HTML and open it in a web browser the default is to show the missing image in the size specified, which is empty.

So basically it's just a question of default behavior when faced with a missing image.  Outlook just does it differently to how various web browsers do.